# Merge nested array and sum the values

Tags: javascript

I have data in following format,

```
const data = [{
        key:'key1',
        rows:[
          ["A","2018","B","1"],
          ["A","2018","C","5"],
          ["A","2018","B","4"],
          ["A","2018","C","2"],
        ]
      },
      {
        key:'key1',
        rows:[
          ["A","2018","B","10"],
          ["A","2018","C","50"],
          ["A","2018","B","40"],
          ["A","2018","C","20"],
        ]
      }]
```

I want to first reduce the `rows` and sum the last value in each array based on 3rd value. Output should be this,

```
const data = [{
        key:'key1',
        rows:[
          ["A","2018","B","5"],
          ["A","2018","C","7"]
        ]
      },
      {
        key:'key1',
        rows:[
          ["A","2018","B","50"],
          ["A","2018","C","70"]
        ]
      }]
```

After this, I want to merge these 2 object and sum the value from `rows`. **The final output should be this,**

```
const data = [{
        key:'key1',
        rows:[
          ["A","2018","B","55"],
          ["A","2018","C","77"]
        ]
      }]
```

I have tried this, but not getting desired output,

```
data.map(data => ({
          ...data,
          rows: data.rows.reduce((array, value) => {
            if(array.length > 0){
              let found = false;
              array.map(m => {
                if(m[2] === value[2]){
                  found = true;
                  return [...m, m[3] = parseInt(m[3]) + parseInt(value[3])]
                }
              })
              if(!found){
                array.push(value)
              }
              return array
            }else{
              array.push(value)
              return array
            }
          }, [])
      }))
```

Comment: one issue could be how the outer "data" and inner "data" have the same variable name, change it and try?

Comment: Why can't you combine all the rows in one go?

Comment: @slider, can you guide me how to merge all the rows at once.

Comment: Are you wanting to merge sets which have the same `key` or are you merging regardless of `key`?

Comment: And in the final merged result, is it correct that if the first three columns are the same for a row, they should be merged, or is it just the third column that is important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is to iterate over the objects to grab the rows and flatten them, then `reduce` over the arrays to aggregate them, finally using `Object.values` to get the correct dataset at the end.

```js
const data = [{ key: 'key1', rows: [ ["A", "2018", "B", "1"], ["A", "2018", "C", "5"], ["A", "2018", "B", "4"], ["A", "2018", "C", "2"] ] }, { key: 'key1', rows: [ ["A", "2018", "B", "10"], ["A", "2018", "C", "50"], ["A", "2018", "B", "40"], ["A", "2018", "C", "20"]]}];

const key = data[0].key;

// Use `flatMap` to iterate over the object and merge the rows
const merged = data.flatMap(el => el.rows);

const rows = Object.values(merged.reduce((acc, c) => {
  const [ k1, k2, k3, k4 ] = c;
  acc[k3] = acc[k3] || [ k1, k2, k3, 0 ];
  acc[k3][3] += +k4;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log([{ key, rows }]);
```

Note: if you need the aggregated number returned to a string simply map over the result:

```
.map(([ a, b, c, d ]) => {
  return [ a, b, c, d.toString() ];
});
```

Further reading

- [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: This will only giving me combined rows, but I want object with `key: 'key1'` like `{
        key:'key1',
        rows:[
          ["A","2018","B","55"],
          ["A","2018","C","77"]
        ]
      }`

Comment: Then add that result to an object. I've updated my answer.